# Android VideoView with HTTP Range headers

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-range

I have web server supporting HTTP Range headers for video content and for `Web Browsers and iOS` works great, but after starting testing on Android application using basic `VideoView` I found that application not making request with `Range: 0-` HTTP header.

I've tried to response with this headers for the beginning, based on HTTP Range header specifications. 
Sending 2 bytes of file header then client will send range for response.

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: public
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 2
Content-Range: 0-1/34568
```

On iOS and Web browsers working with this very well, but Android `VideoView` not sending `Range` header at all.

How to make this work for `VideoView` ?

Comment: `Range: ...` support is not mandatory. Also, if the `VideoView` has not cached the data yet, using `Range` may be considered pointless by that software implementation. For sure, using `Range: 0-` is just the same as a plain `GET` without the `Range` header. Forcing a `Range` reply when the client did not ask for it is likely to fail too.